# When I do npm install ? This issue comes , PLEASE help me solve this issue

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed VS installer 2019 with development workload for c++

but still it is giving error

I also tried deleting and re -installing the node-modules
with rm -rf node-modules command

But still while running npm install error occurs

> fibers@4.0.3 install C:\Users\F1\workspacemobiles-apps\node_modules\fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

```
C:\Users\F1\workspacemobiles-apps\node_modules\fibers>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2017
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.8.30907.101) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.18362.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS - "2019"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\F1\workspacemobiles-apps\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.x (node_modules\appium\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN react-native-fast-image@7.0.2 requires a peer of react-native@^0.60.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-localization@2.1.6 requires a peer of react-native@^0.41.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-localization@2.1.6 requires a peer of react-native-windows@0.41.0-rc.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wdio/jasmine-framework@6.11.0 requires a peer of @wdio/cli@^6.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wdio/appium-service@6.12.1 requires a peer of @wdio/cli@^6.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wdio/local-runner@6.12.1 requires a peer of @wdio/cli@^6.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @wdio/spec-reporter@6.11.0 requires a peer of @wdio/cli@^6.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.20.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@4.0.3 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@4.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\F1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-26T18_25_26_803Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Node onto your computer https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Just install that and then run `npm install`